# Dealing with negative inductor in filter design

Tags: rf, filter

I have been attempting to synthesise some all-pass filters using the S/FILSYN software. The resulting filter design often includes a negative inductor, such as L5 in the included schematic. Does anyone have suggestions on how to realise such a circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGzc2x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The S/FILSYN manual mentions that a grounded inductor (that is, one terminal on ground) can be constructed, but does not go into detail as to how. I also know that the combination of L4, L5 and L6 can be implemented using a pair of coupled inductors, but again don't know the details. I have also found mentions of these two methods in other places, but little detail. In principle, a capacitor might work for the frequency range of interest (118MHz to 137MHz) but I would rather know the proper way to solve this.

PS: To anyone who finds this post while trying to get S/FILSYN to work, a virtual machine running Windows XP 32-bit (mostly) worked for me.

EDIT: corrected typo in L5 value, from H to nH.
EDIT2: corrected typo

Comment: The negative value is only a part of your problem.  The 13.38H is an EXTREMELY large inductance value.  Basically you have a circuit that is unrealizable.  I'm not familiar with S/FILSYN but perhaps if you read through its instructions there might be information on how to get realizable circuits.

Comment: I've seen Frequency Dependent Negative Resistors (FDNRs) realised using opamps : closely related (perhaps identical) to gyrator circuits. So this may be realisable as an active filter element using a similar technique. Whether that's a good idea or not is another matter.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very typical result that basically means you got a garbage output, because something overflowed in the filter synthesis computations, or there was catastrophic loss of precision, or some iterative algorithm failed to converge. Typically, when you start to write filter design software, you'll get such "results". The general idea is to learn enough about numerical methods and other related math not to let such garbage reach the user, because they then ask all sorts of questions :)

Any reasonable filter design will use impedances in the same ballpark (e.g. similar order of magnitude). If you see nanoHenry values intermingled with Henries, it doesn't matter whether the Henries are positive or negative - you can likely toss the output into the junk bin and move on. Nothing to see here, just poorly implemented filter design software. Lots of that out there, unfortunately, because it's  way easier to implement such software to be half broken than fully functional.

A problem I've ran into several times is typos in equations in books. It's even "funnier" when such typos are so nonlinear that they lead to insignificant errors until some threshold is reached in the design, and suddenly nothing works anymore. In that one sad case, I had to re-derive a section in the book from first principles - and I was very young and had nowhere near the requisite background to do it efficiently. It was a slog. These days it's much easier to avoid such blunders, because nobody sane should be using equations from books without plugging them into a legit numerical programming environment like Mathematica and evaluating their performance in all sorts of scenarios both numerically and symbolically.

And just so there are no misconceptions here: the floating point types in C/FORTRAN are implementation details that have to *follow from* other means of analysis/reasoning. I.e. don't test stuff using `double` or `complex` in C or FORTRAN, because they can't be reliably used until you have convinced yourself well that it'll work: use some framework designed to be more general and having much larger numerical range, and good built-in diagnostics that catch runaway errors and provide error bounds and such.

Comment: Last I checked, Mathematica was more of a symbolic than numeric programming environment, but that was nearly ten years ago and it probably got expanded.